# How can I convert all tables in a word document to images?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Below is my attempt but it's producing odd results, and the results seem to change each time i run the macro...

Can anyone see any issues in my code or can think of a better way of doing this?

```
Sub ConvertTablesToImages()

Dim tbl As Table
Dim currentDoc As Document
Set currentDoc = ActiveDocument

For Each tbl In currentDoc.Tables

   tbl.Range.Copy
   Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
   Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
   tbl.Delete

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few problems. One is mixing ranges and selections and the other is deleting members of a collection (in this case tables in the document) while trying to loop through all of them.

Take a look at this revision of your code. It should work better.

```
Sub ConvertTablesToImages()

    Dim tbl As Table, rng As Range, i As Integer
    Dim currentDoc As Document
    Set currentDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    For i = currentDoc.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set tbl = currentDoc.Tables(i)
        Set rng = tbl.Range
        rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        tbl.Range.CopyAsPicture
        tbl.Delete
        rng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
        rng.ShapeRange(1).ConvertToInlineShape
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a variation to Rich's answer for anyone who finds that their tables are being cropped in some of the pasted images.

Adding `tbl.PreferredWidth = 0` seemed to fix this

```
Sub ConvertTablesToImages()

    Dim tbl As Table, rng As Range, i As Integer
    Dim currentDoc As Document
    Set currentDoc = ActiveDocument

    For i = currentDoc.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set tbl = currentDoc.Tables(i)
        Set rng = tbl.Range
        tbl.PreferredWidth = 0
        rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        tbl.Range.CopyAsPicture
        tbl.Delete
        rng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
        rng.ShapeRange(1).ConvertToInlineShape
    Next

End Sub
```